# Creating and accumulating a Map of Map of Map ... in scala

Tags: perl, scala

I have a file containing data on Salesman, Product, Location, SalesValue

For instance:

```
Bob, Carrots, United States, 200
Bill, Potatoes, England, 100
Bob, Oranges, England, 50
Bob, Carrots, United States, 20
```

The SalesValue can be succinctly accumulated into a hash of hash of hash in perl using the following code

```
while(<>){
    @cols = split(/,/);
    $vals {$cols[0]} {$cols[1]} {$cols[2]} += $cols[3];
}
```

Has anyone got any suggestions how this creation of a map of map of map, plus the accumulation , could best be implemented in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to see the merging of these maps as a `monoid-append` operation.

First we create the maps of maps of maps as single elements:

```
val input = """Bob, Carrots, United States, 200
              |Bill, Potatoes, England, 100
              |Bob, Oranges, England, 50
              |Bob, Carrots, United States, 20""".stripMargin.lines.toList

val mmm = input.map(_.split(", "))
               .map { case Array(n, g, c, v) => Map(n -> Map(g -> Map(c -> v.toInt))) }
```

`mmm` is of type `List[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]]` :

```
    List[Map[String, 
                    Map[String, 
                               Map[String, Int]]]]
```

Then we could `suml` using a library like `scalaz` or `cats`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

println(mmm.suml)
```

This will print (not idented):

```
Map(Bill -> Map(Potatoes -> Map(England -> 100)), 
    Bob  -> Map(Oranges  -> Map(England -> 50), 
                Carrots  -> Map(United States -> 220)))
```

To help understand what is happening behind the `.suml` operation I would **shamelessly** suggest to checkout this presentation I made last year https://speakerdeck.com/filippovitale/will-it-blend-scalasyd-february-2015

---

**EDIT**

We can also see our maps of maps of maps as `Foldable` and use `foldMap` for the same result:

```
input.map(_.split(", "))
     .foldMap{ case Array(n, g, c, v) => Map(n -> Map(g -> Map(c -> v.toInt))) }
```

Comment: In other words, Perl is the winner here ;)

Comment: ...yes, but I wait for Perl6 before using it again :-P After this troll I will update the answer with some more detailed explanation and an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

Filippo Vitale codes are more concise and elegant

This is a bruteforce solution:

```
val t =
  """Bob, Carrots, United States, 200
    |Bill, Potatoes, England, 100
    |Bob, Oranges, England, 50
    |Bob, Carrots, United States, 20""".stripMargin

def commaSplit(s: String) = s.splitAt(s.indexOf(","))

def f(arg: Seq[String]) =
  arg
    .groupBy(commaSplit(_)._1)
    .map{ case (key, values) => key -> values.map(commaSplit(_)._2.drop(2))}

val res =
  f(t.split("\n"))
    .map{ case (key, values) => key -> f(values).map { case (k, v) =>
      k -> f(v).map { case (country, amount) => country -> amount.map(_.toInt).sum }
    }}
```

that gives this result:

```
Map(Bob ->  Map(Carrots  -> Map(United States -> 220), 
                Oranges  -> Map(England -> 50)), 
    Bill -> Map(Potatoes -> Map(England -> 100)))
```